# Neural networks in evolution simulator- how to calculate error without expected result

Tags: java, neural-network

I am creating an evolution simulator in Java. The simulation consists of a map with cold/hot regions and high/low elevation, etc'.
I want the creatures in the world to evolve in two ways- every single creature will evolve it's AI during the course of his lifetime, and when a creature reproduces there is a chance for mutation. 
I thought it would be good to make the brain of the creatures a neural network that takes the sensor's data as input (only eyes at the moment), and produces commands to the thrusters (which move the creature around).

However, I only have experience with basic neural networks that recieve desired inputs from the user and calculate the error accordingly. However in this simulator, there is no optimal result. Results can be rated by a fitness function I have created (which takes in count energy changes, amount of offsprings, etc'), but it is unknown which output node is wrong and which is right.

1. Am I using the correct approach for this problem? Or perhaps neural networks are not the best solution for it?
2. If it is a viable way to achieve what I desire, how can I make the neural network adjust the correct weights if I do not know them?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for any english mistakes.

Comment: This brilliant tutorial describes the exact kind of scenarios you're talking about, and I think you'll find it really helpful. http://www.ai-junkie.com/ga/intro/gat1.html

Comment: So you are saying that I should use a genetic algorithm instead of a neural network?

Comment: @AlexT. The problem is that I can't generate more then one decision at a time, because every creature would have to make it every single tick. I want to be able to choose what to do, and then learn what to do next time according to the outcome of the decision.

Comment: Honestly, there's a part of me thinks that a neural network is slightly overkill for what's being displayed. Have you ever seen Game of Life code? I think the problems you pose, using eyes as input on this heat map, will be well defined, whereas neural networks are for ill-posed problems. Like, once you figure out what good and bad is on the heatmap, what is there to really train?

Comment: Maybe you should look into path planning algorithms like the Potential Field Map?

Comment: @AlexT. The thing is that I don't want a pre-programed AI to control a creature. Of course it is possible to make the creatures very smart using pre-defined good and bad AI, but the point is to let every creature learn what is good himself.

Answer (score 0):

You ran into a common problem with neural networks and games. As mentioned in the comments a Genetic algorithm is often used when there is no 'correct' solution. 
So your goal is basically to somehow combine neural networks and genetic algorithms. Luckily somebody did this before and described the process in this [paper](http://nn.cs.utexas.edu/keyword?stanley:ec02).

Since the paper is relatively complex and it is very time consumeing to implemwnt the algorithm you should consider using a library.
Since I couldn't find any suiting library for me, I decided to write my own one, you can find it [here](http://github.com/PLEXATIC/Neuratic)
The library should work good enough for 'smaller' problems like yours. You will find some example code in the Main class.

Combine networks using

```
Network.breedWith(Network other);
```

Create networks using

```
Network net = new Network(int inputs, int outputs);
```

Mutate networks using

```
Network.innovate();
```

As you will see in the example code it is important to always have an initial amount of mutations for each new network. This is because when you create a new network there are **no** connections, so innovation (fancy word for mutation) is needed to create connections.
If needed you can always create copys of networks (Network.getCopy();). The Network class and all of its attributes implement serializable, so you can save/load a network using an ObjectOutputStream.

If you decide to use my library please let me know what results you got!